# Flutter-Firebase rtdb, fetching child values return as empty

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve a child's value from firebase RTDB and putting them into a list, but the values return empty, upon printing the list, it is empty too. The code used to work without any issues, the only changes I made was updating Flutter and dependencies to the latest versions.

Code:

```
lastPosition() async {
    print(searchID);
    // This method grabs the stream of location that is being sent to the database
    print("\n\n\nFetching Coordinates\n\n");
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        .child("Driver Coordinates")
        .child(searchID)
        .once()
        .then(
      (DataSnapshot lastPosSnapshot) {
        setState(
          () {
            lastLatLng.add(
              lastPosSnapshot.value["latitude"],
            );
            lastLatLng.add(
              lastPosSnapshot.value["longitude"],
            );
            Future.delayed(
              Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
    print(lastLatLng);
    await getAdressBasedLocation();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, and while that is happening your main code continues to execute. In practice this means that your `print(lastLatLng);` runs before any of the `lastLatLng.add(...)` calls after ever executed, something you can most easily check by adding some logging inside the `then()` handler too.

In practice this means that any code that needs the data from the database has to be *inside* the `then` callback, or you have to use `await` to block the `once` call (in which case you also have to mark `lastPosition` as `async` and use `await` or `then` on any calls to it.

So moving the call to inside the `then` callback:

```
databaseReference
    .child("users")
    .child("Driver Coordinates")
    .child(searchID)
    .once()
    .then((DataSnapshot lastPosSnapshot) {
    lastLatLng.add(lastPosSnapshot.value["latitude"]);
    lastLatLng.add(lastPosSnapshot.value["longitude"]);

    print(lastLatLng); // 
    ...
  },
);
```

Or by using `await`:

```
var lastPosSnapshot = await databaseReference
    .child("users")
    .child("Driver Coordinates")
    .child(searchID)
    .once();
lastLatLng.add(lastPosSnapshot.value["latitude"]);
lastLatLng.add(lastPosSnapshot.value["longitude"]);

print(lastLatLng); //
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Frank. I tried making the above changes but I get the same result, Empty value and empty list.

Comment: Since the code in my answer is quite different, I'd at the very least expect to see a change in behavior. Can you add the updated code to your answer? It'd also help to see the JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that the code is reading. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I apologize for the late response. Your second solution worked, I had a ".clear", clearing everything in the list while calling the function from a loop. That was my mistake. Thank you for your help.